# Replace 00 with varbinary type

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that decompiles the value stored in the varbinary type. If I remove from the varbinary value 00, I get the data that gives me the correct result. How to remove the value of 00 from this type without changing it to varchar, or how to return after changing to varchar and converting individual characters to the correct varbinary entry.

if I use swapping on varchar then I can not use the sql query:
REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(max),val,1),'00','')

SQL Query:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(id int identity(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,val varbinary(max));

INSERT INTO @MyTable(val)
SELECT 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
UNION ALL
SELECT 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

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),val) As NormalConvert
FROM @MyTable
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no *efficient* way to do this. Converting the string to a hexstring (and back after replacing) *almost* works, but `REPLACE(str, '00', '')` is not correct -- it would turn `0x1003` into `0x13`, which is wrong. `00` must be replaced only where it occurs in even positions, and that requires an expensive substring split. More pertinently would perhaps be to ask why you're doing this -- if you want to do string searches on .NET executables, there are better approaches than T-SQL (like [`strings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/strings)).

Comment: Thanks,
after changing to text, I need to find information in the string e.g.

Comment: Runtime.ConfigurationDictionary.NumerOperatora == 4) || *(Runtime.ConfigurationDictionary.NumerOperatora == 6) || *(Runtime.ConfigurationDictionary.NumerOperatora == 8) || *(Runtime.ConfigurationDictionary.NumerOperatora == 11) || *(Runtime.ConfigurationDictionary.NumerOperatora == 22) || *(Runtime.ConfigurationDictionary.NumerOperatora == 41

Comment: This is data that an application should insert into a table, not something you distill from (clumsily!) trying to reverse engineer the binary. This technique is very brittle because T-SQL's support for string handling is poor, and there are many ways of encoding such information. Extracting the different `NumerOperatora` values from this string in T-SQL is another exercise in suffering all on its own, for example. You seem to be looking for an embedded XML resource that then has data in its tags somewhere. Surely there are easier ways of getting at it then dissecting an .EXE.

Comment: Out of intellectual curiosity: `SELECT Condition = x.value('(//ActionGroup/Condition)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') FROM (SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), SUBSTRING(@x, CHARINDEX(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), N'<?xml'), @x), (CHARINDEX(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), N'</LiteCallbackGenerator>'), @x) - CHARINDEX(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), N'<?xml'), @x)) + DATALENGTH(N'</LiteCallbackGenerator>'))))) _`. This works only because SQL Server does have support for XML. Futher parsing the condition, however, is a completely different matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit, that I didn't really get what you tried to achieve. This might be a case of an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)...

But - as far as I can understand - you want to transform this varbinaries to readable text, by getting rid of unreadable characters. One trick might be this:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE(id int identity(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,val varbinary(max));

INSERT INTO @MyTable(val)
SELECT 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
UNION ALL
SELECT 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


;WITH SingleCharacters AS
(
    SELECT t.id
          ,Nmbr
          ,OneChar
    FROM @MyTable t
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP(DATALENGTH(t.val)/2) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values v1 CROSS JOIN master..spt_values v2) A(Nmbr)
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(t.val,(-1+Nmbr*2),2) AS VARCHAR(1))) B(OneChar)
)
SELECT sc.id
      ,(
        SELECT sc2.OneChar AS [*]
        FROM SingleCharacters sc2
        WHERE sc2.id=sc.id
        AND ASCII(sc2.OneChar) BETWEEN 32 AND 126
        ORDER BY sc2.Nmbr
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM SingleCharacters sc
GROUP BY sc.id;
```

The idea in short:

The characters are taken from the `VARBINARY` with `SUBSTRING` at any odd position we pick two bytes. This is casted to `VARCHAR(1)`.

The final `SELECT` will use a `GROUP BY` together with a *correlated sub-query*. Starting with v2017 you should use `STRING_AGG()` for the same. This will re-concatenate alle characters with ASCII-values between 32 and 126, hence most of the plain latin characters.

For the given binaries the result is:

```
ML!hspormcno erni O oePL\! @)@( .et`rrD@.eoB)t 2~Do.~*ooo)***?m eso=10 noig"t-6?<iealakeeao mn:s=ht:/w.3og20/MShm-ntne mn:s=ht:/w.3og20/MShm" <cinru>  Cniini RnieCniuainitoayNmrprtr =4 |*RnieCniuainitoayNmrprtr =6 |*RnieCniuainitoayNmrprtr =8 |*RnieCniuainitoayNmrprtr =1)| (utm.ofgrtoDcinr.ueOeaoa= 2 |*RnieCniuainitoayNmrprtr =4)*eunflele{rtr re<Cniin  <aeNw rp<Nm> /cinru>/iealakeeao>SBv..01$#Srns#SGI#lb%/ga = R!1.lMdl>yr_eutdlodtossolbytmbetodto_oaguacoCnyrHdaalaksebyecitoAtiueytmRnieCmieSrieCmiaineaainAtiueutmCmaiiiytrbtHdaRslRnieofgrtoDcinrgtNmrprtrdsrpin "Ab1\6&9etwPoitrAUHL.21...2-421TrpoEcpinhos )CrlMimcredl%X\\4SVRINIFDVrienornltoSrnFlIf0040FlDsrpin8FlVrin...Dnenlaeyr_eutdlLgloyih OiiaFlnmHdaRsl.l4rdcVrin...8sebyVrin...,
M@!Ti rga antb u nDSmd.$PLU@KH.et .sc@.eo@HtZU~Do.~*ooo)***V<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><LiteCallbackGenerator xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  <ActionGroup>    <Condition>if ((Runtime.ConfigurationDictionary.NumerOperatora == 4) ||  (Runtime.ConfigurationDictionary.NumerOperatora == 6) ||  (Runtime.ConfigurationDictionary.NumerOperatora == 8) ||  (Runtime.ConfigurationDictionary.NumerOperatora == 11) ||  (Runtime.ConfigurationDictionary.NumerOperatora == 22) ||  (Runtime.ConfigurationDictionary.NumerOperatora == 41)  ){return false;}else{return true;}</Condition>    <Name>Nowa grupa</Name>  </ActionGroup></LiteCallbackGenerator>BJv..01l$#8#tig#S#UD#lbG%6/gaaaP=RRR%!R)*1.R.2.l.u&X*Mdl>HdaRsl.lodtosmcriytmOjcodto_oagua.trCnyryralaksebyecitoAtiueSse.utm.oplrevcsCmiaineaainAtiueRnieoptbltAtiueHdaRslutmofgrtoDcinre_ueOeaoadsrpin %g\6  9TsoarfleAUHL.090002-421TrpoEcpinhos_oDlanmcredl0HX\\4VS_VERSION_INFO?DVarFileInfo$TranslationStringFileInfo000004b0,FileDescription 0FileVersion0.0.0.0DInternalNameHydra_Result.dll(LegalCopyright LOriginalFilenameHydra_Result.dll4ProductVersion0.0.0.08Assembly Version0.0.0.0
```

This looks not so bad in my eyes.

Hint: You can use some kind of `CASE` list or a mapping table to replace certain ASCII values with the appropriate character.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint of solving this problem. I still have to extract them in the Runtime.ConfigurationDictionary.NumerOperatora. The intended goal of the whole solution is to download the ID of the operators who have access to the solution, and this is stored in this varbinary